# Treat nodes as a HTML link in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

In my app I am using cytoscape.js as a visualization of dependencies among objects. There is a special page for each object with its description and user should be able to click on the node and view its page.

I am using `vmousedown` event to realize these links. It works, however it isn't user friendly, it doesn't work on mobile devices and you cannot open the page in a new tab or get url of the target page.

Is it possible to treat cytoscape.js nodes as HTML link? Or is there a way how to emulate this behavior?

Comment: cyto is vanilla js, you can add `cy.on('click', 'node', function(e) {..})` event and get your data (or other things to run) when you click on a node

Comment: There's even an example that does this exactly... http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/eb861f83fb741628342f/